# C++ few beginner errors

Tags: c++

Not very good at debugging yet but I'm getting a few errors. A few expected '(' ')' and ';'
Also 'else' without a previous 'if', no match for 'operator>>' in cout

I know this is easy, but still trying to get my foot in the door. Thanks :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()   // guess number game
{
    int x;
    cout >> "Please enter a number\n";
    getline(cin x);
    int y = rand();

    while x != y
    {

        if x < y;
           cout >> "Go higher";
        else;
           cout >> "Go lower";
    }


}
```

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: Nothing to debug here, since all your problems appear to be syntax errors.

Comment: It's not homewok, and I'm not sure how to fix the syntax errors

Comment: I don't get what I'm doing wrong...I'm just starting, no one's helping because I'm asking wrong or something?

Comment: You should first learn about syntax and how to use `getline & if-else` before using them in your code.

Comment: Lookup the syntax of `while` and `if` in a beginner's textbook and also how `cout` and `cin` is used correctly and never give up to learn.

Comment: Now it's just spamming "Go higher/lower" without letting me change the value, hopefully someone is still here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cout >> "Please enter a number\n";
```

This is wrong, `std::ostreams` only provide the [`operator<<`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) to insert formatted data. Use `cout << "Please enter a number\n";` instead.

```
getline(cin x);
```

First, you're missing a `,`, since [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) needs two or three arguments. But since `x` is an `integer` and not a `std::string` it is still wrong. Think about it - can you store a text line inside of an integer? Use `cin >> x` instead.

```
int y = rand();
```

While this doesn't seem wrong there's a logical error. `rand()` is a pseudo random number generator. It uses a seed as start value and some kind of algorithm (`a*m + b`). Thus you have to specify a start value, also called seed. You can specify this by using `srand()`. The same seed will result in the same order of numbers, so use something like `srand(time(0))`.

```
while x != y
if x < y;
```

Use parenthesis. And drop the additional `;`. A stray semicolon `;` in your program resembles the empty expression.

**EDIT**: Working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main(){
    int x;
    int y;
    srand(time(0));
    y = rand();
    std::cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    do{
        if(std::cin >> x){
            if(x < y)
                std::cout << "Go higher: ";
            if(x > y)
                std::cout << "Go lower: ";    
        }
        else{
            // If the extraction fails, `std::cin` will evaluate to false
            std::cout << "That wasn't a number, try again: ";
            std::cin.clear(); // Clear the fail bits
        }
    }while(x != y);
    std::cout << "Congratulations, you guessed my number :)";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you use `g++` to compile then use `-Wall -Wextra` to get more warnings - this will help you to find your mistakes faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void main()
{
  int x;
  cout << "Please enter a number\n";
  getline(cin, x);
  int y = rand();

  while(x != y)
  {
   if(x < y)
    cout << "Go higher";
   else
     cout << "Go lower";
  }
}
```

Comment: What's up with that dangling else? And with cout that tries to send something into a string?

Comment: @PaoloBrandoli It is typo. Corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Not overly familiar with C++ but i'm pretty sure the while/if should look something like this

```
 while (x != y)
{

 if (x < y)
    cout << "Go higher";
 else
    cout << "Go lower";
}
```

the conditions of both if and while loops should be nested with parenthesis.

Comment: The cout needs to use a "<<" operator instead of ">>" operator.

Answer (score 0):

everything you listed above are syntax errors. This can be easily fixed by reading up on the syntax of c++

http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/tapestry/howtoa.pdf

it should look more like this:

```
 while (x != y)
 {

     if (x < y)
        cout >> "Go higher";
     else
        cout >> "Go lower";
  }
```

Comment: The cout needs to use a "<<" operator instead of ">>" operator.

Comment: wasn't planning on fixing all the errors but just got starting with the first ones that were being hit.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at all the errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()   // guess number game
{
    int x;
    cout >> "Please enter a number\n"; // should be `cout <<` cin uses >>
    getline(cin x); // incorrect number of arguments should be 2 or 3 plus x is an int not string could use cin instead
    int y = rand();

    while x != y // error condition checks should be parentheses like (x != y)
    {

        if x < y; // error condition should be parentheses also by adding a semicolon here you terminate the statement
           cout >> "Go higher";
        else; // technically not an error but unintended code is executed cout >> "Go higher" is always executed because of the semi colon ;
           cout >> "Go lower";
    }

// no return of value, you declared main to return an int so you should
}
```

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()   // guess number game
{
    int x;
    cout << "Please enter a number\n";
    cin >> x;
    int y = rand();

    while (x != y)
    {

        if (x < y)
           cout >> "Go higher";
        else
           cout >> "Go lower";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The cout needs to use a "<<" operator instead of ">>" operator.